# Complex UI with MVC

Tags: qt, user-interface, model-view-controller, pyqt

I'm trying to recreate a text editor I've made but using the MVC design pattern; I'm not totally sure about certain parts of it.

For example, I have a tree view displaying my project directory, and a text editor showing the contents of a file, along with this i have output from compilation of files being displayed as well as a tabbed interface.

Would this be split into a few different models or under one big model?  If it's under 1 big model how would I go about using the Qt model classes for such a thing?

Comment: This question is probably also well suited for programmers.stackexchange

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open up Qt Designer and drag and drop all the stuff you need.  It should get you pretty far.

I think the only model/view you should worry about is the `QFileSystemModel` and pairing it up with a `QTreeView`.  Everything else Qt has some nice examples showing how to do it.

If you are showing multiple files at once in separate tabs, then you might want to look into the Tabbed Browser Example to see how its done.

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/examples-mainwindow.html

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-richtext-syntaxhighlighter-example.html

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-widgets-codeeditor-example.html

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwebkitexamples-webkitwidgets-browser-example.html

I like `QDockWidgets` and using `QActions` and putting them on the `QToolbar` in a `QMainWindow`.

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/model-view-programming.html

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfilesystemmodel.html#details

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmdiarea.html#details

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextedit.html

For the compilation part you will just need to create a `QProcess` and connect its output to a `QTextEdit`.

Hope that helps.

Comment: i understand that part, but would i still set up a separate class for some kind of model to hold the data for the UI, and perform the processing, and why does Qt leave out the controller aspect of MVC and only use Model/View?

Comment: Qt recommends using a specialized controller called a delegate, that helps modularize the access to individual elements.  I've used it on a few projects and the organization makes sense.  Looking into the code on all the examples really shows off why it is a good design pattern.  It makes it very consistent when representing data in different kinds of views and doing common tasks with individual items.  It is really powerful, but does have its learning curve.